# I need to call an EntityFunctions method in a dynamic EF Filter generation. How?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, datetime

We have implemented a method of dynamically creating Lambda filters using some reflection and other methods.  Most of what I want is working beautifully.  The problem is when it comes to DateTime values and equality/greater than/less than filters.

Our SQL server is storing the items as DateTime objects and sometimes the Time is specified for specific items.  However, when displaying a list on the web, we are only showing the date.  So when the user (using Kendo Grid) tries to filter the data to dates greater than or something similar, it is using midnight the day of as it parameter.  This means all items that happened after midnight on that day are included when they shouldn't be.  It also means that when we use a equals statement, nothing is returned as there is very little that happens exactly at midnight.

My research (using Stack Overflow) led me to using `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime` as a method.  I'm not sure if I am to do it to both the field and the filtering value or not, but I can't even get past the value for now.

My first try was to set the right side of my comparison (the value portion) to a call to `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(filter.Value)`.  This gave me a `This function can only be invoked by linq to entities` error.  Further research lead me to using the Expression.Call method, but currently I am getting an exception of `No method 'TruncateTime' on type 'System.Data.Objects.EntityFunctions' is compatible with the supplied arguments.`

Below is my code where I try to make the call.  I provided the entire function for context.  I created a GetPropertyType function to let me know if I am filtering on a DateTime field.  I also added a property to my Filter object to tell me if I should ignore time or not.  If both are true, only then do I try and apply the TruncateTime function.

I've also tried specifying the type of DateTime as a type argument to the Expression.Constant call in the method, just in case it needed to be typed, but that didn't help either.

```
    public static Expression GetLambdaFilters(ICollection<Filter> filters)
    {
        if (filters.Count > 0)
        {
            Type entityType = filters.ElementAt(0).EntityType;
            var item = Expression.Parameter(entityType, entityType.Name);
            Expression leftSide = null;
            Expression rightSide = null;
            Expression filterExpression = null;
            foreach (var filter in filters)
            {

                Expression left = GetPropertyExpression(filter, item);
                Expression comparison = null;
                if (left is MethodCallExpression)
                {
                    comparison = left;
                }
                else
                {
                    Expression right = null;
                    if (!filter.IsCollectionQuery)
                    {
                        if (GetPropertyType(filter) == typeof (DateTime) && filter.IgnoreTime)
                        {
                                right = Expression.Call(typeof (EntityFunctions), "TruncateTime", null,
                                    Expression.Constant(filter.Value));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            right = Expression.Constant(filter.Value);
                        }


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Filter innerFilter = new Filter();
                        innerFilter.IsCollectionQuery = false;
                        innerFilter.Operator = filter.Operator;
                        innerFilter.PropertyName = GetCollectionPropertyName(filter, item);
                        innerFilter.Type = filter.CollectionType;
                        innerFilter.Value = filter.Value;
                        List<Filter> innerfilters = new List<Filter>(){
                        innerFilter
                    };
                        right = GetLambdaFilters(innerfilters);
                        filter.Operator = FilterOperator.Any;
                    }
                    comparison = GetExpression(left, right, filter);
                }
                if (leftSide == null)
                {
                    leftSide = comparison;
                    filterExpression = leftSide;
                    continue;
                }
                if (rightSide == null)
                {
                    rightSide = comparison;
                    filterExpression = Expression.AndAlso(leftSide, rightSide);
                    continue;
                }
                filterExpression = Expression.AndAlso(filterExpression, comparison);
            }
            var func = typeof(Func<,>);
            func.MakeGenericType(entityType, typeof(bool));
            return Expression.Lambda(func.MakeGenericType(entityType, typeof(bool)), filterExpression, item);
        }
        else
        {
            return GetLambdaFilter(filters.First());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the line:

```
right = Expression.Call(typeof (EntityFunctions), "TruncateTime", null,
                                Expression.Constant(filter.Value));
```

to

```
right = Expression.Call(typeof (EntityFunctions), "TruncateTime", null,
Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(DateTime.Parse(filter.Value)), typeof(DateTime?)));
```

this should work. Its the boxing conversion part that wont happen without the convert call that is causing the error.